# Mix a configurable product with custom options

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, simple-product

We're trying to achieve a certain functionality using Magento and wondering what is the best way.

The scenario is as follows and similar to this page: https://www.go-in.co.uk/chairs/14424/grand-bistro-chair-0650/

Item Page:

1. Each product (a chair in this instance) has both "pre-defined" options and "customization options".
2. Each of the "pre-defined" options has a unique product URL, image, description and price.
3. Each of the "customization options", based upon the selection, has a unique product image, description and price (no unique URL in this case).

Category Page with Layered Navigation:

In the category page:

1. Only one main product (which is in the list of "pre-defined") is shown for each of the configurations.
2. Upon filtering, choose only one product configuration from the "pre-defined" list (https://www.go-in.co.uk/chairs/?f_152=7644) and show it in the category page.

Comments:

1. Let's assume we have an image available for each of the product's selections (which includes the "customization options" selections).
2. There is another set of items - think of a sofa. These items also have color options but also have a height and length options. We do not want to combine these in an attribute but simply as a custom option selection.

We were thinking of using a configurable product as the main product, with certain amount of "pre-defined options". These will have to be set to "not visible individually" and we will have to pull them somehow only when filtered. The issue with this approach comes into play on second set of sofa items where we would also like to include other type of options which are not described in attributes via the configurable product.

Your suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!